# Perl CGI Functional Programming - generating links

Tags: html, perl, hyperlink, functional-programming, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script. I'm trying to generate **hyperlinks** on an HTML page using all the elements in an array. I'm using functional CGI style programming. Here's a minimal representation of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI qw( :standard);

print header;

print start_html(
    -title => 'Get LINK!'
);

my %HoA = (
    'foo' =>  [ '12', '23', '593' ],
    'bam' => [ '232', '65' ],
);

my @array = ("foo", "bam");
foreach my $i (@array){
    foreach my $j (@{$HoA{$i}}){
        my $link = get_link($i);
        print "<a href="$link" target="_blank">$i</a>"."\t"; # this doesn't work!!
    }
}
#-----------------------------------
# this subroutine works!
sub get_link{
    my $id = $_[0];
    my $link = 'http://www.example.com/'.$id;
    return $link;
}
#------------------------------------
```

## Desired Output

[foo](https://www.example.com/12)   [foo](https://www.example.com/23)   [foo](https://www.example.com/593) [bam](https://www.example.com/232) [bam](https://www.example.com/65)

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    print "<a href="$link" target="_blank">$g</a>"."\t"; # this doesn't work!!
```

that's because your quotes in your quote end your quote.  You need to escape them:

```
    print "<a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\">$g</a>"."\t"; # this doesn't work!!
```

single quotes work on the inside, too.

As per the comment, qq-style quoting is also available to you, so you can use double quotes and variable interpolation at the same time without the escape characters.

Comment: You could also make that a little more readable by using `qq` to avoid all the backslash escaping.

Comment: there are way more problems than just this

Comment: The question was specifically about that line (see source), and he called out that it wasn't the original code, so I wasn't going to dive deep onto what he may have just mis-typed or omitted.

Comment: No, fixing the quoting won't fix his problem, although it is part of the issue. The real problem is that `$link` is a `ref`. Unless `http://google.com/ARRAY(0x0x7fd8598070d0)` is a valid link.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose he wouldn't have seen that until he fixed his quoting.

Comment: @xaxxon right, the first thing I would have done, if I were him, was replace that `print` statement with a simple `print $link, "\n"`; which would have shown him part of the problem.

Comment: duly noted. thanks guys. @chrsblck I replied to your comment below.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that don't make much sense.

The code below doesn't work because `$link` is a ref. Also, you're not using `$j` anywhere, 
which should give you a sign that there's a bit of a "design" issue.

```
foreach my $i (@array){
    foreach my $j (@{$HoA{$i}}){
        my $link = get_link($i);
        print "<a href="$link" target="_blank">$g</a>"."\t"; # this doesn't work!!
    }
}
```

Why can't this be rewritten like so:

```
for my $array_ref (keys %HoA) {
    for my $item ( @{ $HoA{$array_ref} } ){
        my $link = get_link($item);
        # print ....
    }
}
```

How does this sub "work"? `$id` is an array reference here. Do you just mean to `shift` onto $id?

```
#-----------------------------------
# this subroutine works!
sub get_link{
    #my $id = $HoA{$_[0]};
    # with the refactored double for loop, or the way you had it if you fix the 
    # `ref` issue, a `shift` should do the trick.
    my $id = shift;
    my $link = 'http://www.google.com/'.$id;
    return $link;
}
#------------------------------------
```

You also need to escape the quotes in `print` statement:

```
print "<a href="$link" target="_blank">$g</a>"."\t";
```

Comment: yep I fixed the subroutine. see above. then apply xannon's answer to the problem line. thanks for catching that.

Comment: @cooldood3490 again, to reiterate. why are you creating a new array that is the same as your `keys` in your `hash`(associative array)? See above refactor of your code. Waste of memory, you're going to maintain the second `@array`, and what is `$j` for?

Comment: in my original script I have two HoA data structures. I loop through the keys of the second HoA (not shown above). I omitted the second HOA (and just write the keys as an array) in my question to simplify the representation.

Comment: @cooldood3490 That doesn't make sense. Still sounds like you're doing something wrong. `@array` is supposed to be what then, `keys %HoA2`? Both `hashes` contain the same `keys`?

Comment: this was just a proof of concept. I needed to know how to generate a hyperlink using Perl CGI Functional Programming. Your solution above helped me get it and is actually BETTER (more efficient) than the OP. that's why I gave you a +1. I will apply your solution once I get the hyperlinks up. I appreciate the help, really. You're essentially forcing me to become a better programmer.

Comment: @chrsblck: in the code as presented, there is an array and a hash of arrays; the array gives the order in which the hash should be accessed; removing it and just using keys makes the order indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can do this ...

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);

print header,
      start_html(-title => 'Get LINK!');

my %HoA = (
     foo => [ qw(12 23 593) ],
     bam => [ qw(232 65) ],
);

foreach my $i ( reverse sort keys %HoA )  {
      foreach ( @{$HoA{$i}} )  {
        print a({-href => 'http:/www.google.com/'.$_, 
                 -target => '_blank'}, $i) . "\n";
      }
}
```

Output:

```
foo foo foo bam bam
```